# Bash command line env vars

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

If you do this (in bash):

```
ENV_ONE=1 ENV_TWO=2 command
```

`command` will accept and use the environment variables in its invocation. BUT, if you do this:

```
ENV_ONE=1 ENV_TWO=2 clear && command
```

`clear` will consume the env vars set on the command line, and they will not be passed to command. This is a problem if you want to do something like:

```
alias command='clear && command'
```

I've googled around and I can't find a bash builtin that represents the env vars prior to a command. My question is: **how can i pass the CLI declared env vars to the second command?**

Comment: clear THEN set them? `clear && ENV1=.. ENV2=... command`?

Comment: Just because you can do multiple declarations without any in-between logic, I don't see why you ever would, since it doesn't really coincide with anything else in bash. So just do `ENV_ONE=1 && ENV_TWO=2 && clear && command` or `ENV_ONE=1; ENV_TWO=2; clear && command` depending on whether or not you really need them to depend on one another

Comment: @BroSlow, `ENV_ONE=1; foo` is not the same as `ENV_ONE=1 foo`. They do different things: The former sets a shell variable, which persists even after the command is complete; the latter sets an environment variable only for the execution of the command `foo`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fair point, upvoting `the other guy's` answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule of thumb with aliases is "if you have to ask, use a function instead". Since `command` clashes with a builtin, I'll call your command `foo`:

```
foo() { clear && command foo "$@"; }
ENV_ONE=1 ENV_TWO=2 foo
```

This works as expected.

Comment: +1 -- this is exactly the answer we'd give someone who asked this question in #bash.

Comment: Most of the good bash answers on SO are informed by Freenode #bash. :P

Comment: this is precisely the answer i was looking for! sorry i wasn't more careful with my terms (choice of `command` as generic command name) Thanks!